# Why there is no ServletRequestBindingListener?

Tags: servlets, servlet-listeners

We have HttpSessionBindingListener to notify an object when it is bound to/unbound from a session. Why there is no such mechanism to notify objects that are added to a ServletRequest?

Answer (score 0):

No-one has presented a use case to the Servlet Expert Group demonstrating why such an interface is required. Given the different lifecycles of HttpSession and ServletRequest, an immediate use case doesn't come to mind.

Comment: Well, think of an use case that is similar to the one for HttpSessionBindingListener.